# Plot multiple plots dependent on value in column

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, facet

I have a data frame that consists of Median, 1 and 3 percentile, ID, and group. Here is some test data, but real data consist of over 500 rows.

```
data <- data.frame( "County" = c(1,1,2,2,3,3), "Median" = c(5,7,8,2,4,5), "Low" = c(0.5,2,4,1,2,3), "High" = c(10,12,11,9,10,15), "ID" = c("TRUE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE"), "group" = c(1,1,2,2,3,3))
```

I will always have a duplicate of "County" and in my plot, I want to show two geom_crossbars on top of each other (showing ID = TRUE/FALSE), SEE FIGURE. But now I would like to plot only the data that is included for group = 1, etc. And finally, I would like to get one plot for each group on a facet scheme.

This is my ggplot so far:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = as.factor(County), 
                y = Median, 
                ymin = Low, 
                ymax = High)) +
  geom_crossbar(aes(color = ID, fill = ID, alpha = 1)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("gray79", "brown4")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("gray50", "brown4")) +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_alpha(guide = "none") +
  xlab("County") +
  ylab("Variance") +
  labs(fill = "Model") +
  labs(color = "Model")
```

[image]

I am not sure how to plot only the data that is included in a specific argument. Have anyone else experienced this?

Comment: `+ facet_wrap(~group, scales = 'free')` ?

Comment: That was easy :) THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `facet_wrap`/`facet_grid` to your code.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data, aes(x = as.factor(County), 
                 y = Median, 
                 ymin = Low, 
                 ymax = High)) +
  geom_crossbar(aes(color = ID, fill = ID, alpha = 1)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("gray79", "brown4")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("gray50", "brown4")) +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_alpha(guide = "none") +
  xlab("County") +
  ylab("Variance") +
  labs(fill = "Model") +
  labs(color = "Model")  +
  facet_wrap(~group, scales = 'free')
```

[image]